# Object Property Browser for Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I`d like to write a property browser (like .NET propertygrid) for my javascript objects  but as a new javascript developer ,I am not sure what is the best way to manage attributes etc. in javascript.

As a C# developer I could use attributes like

```
[Category("My Properties")]
[Description("Simple Properties")]
[DisplayName("MyText")]
public string SomeText
{
    get { return someText; }
    set { someText = value; }
}
```

so my property browser knows necessary information about the properties of my class.
It is also important to know the type of property . For example if the type of property is date, the  property browser should show a date picker.

My first idea was using variable names.

```
this.date_StartDate
this.int_Length
```

and then property grid could just cut off first part of the name and shows
StartDate  as a datetime property and 
Length as an integer property.

Please let me know if there is a better method.

Comment: Are you looking to build something similar to `console.dir()`, which is a property browser?

Comment: kind of. A graphical console.dir() maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real "best" way, although I'd advise against using variable names to signify types.

If you need to support custom types, color for example, I would take the following approach:

My approach would be to add a type to all objects yourself, as a property:

```
var date = {
  value: "31/01/2015",
  type: "date"
};
```

You could also add a type object, as a sort of enum, so you won't spell your types wrong any time.

```
var types = {
   date: "date",
   number: "number"
};
```

This is not needed as long as you use native JavaScript types, like number, string, date and such.

In my own property browser experiment, I simply use typeof to determine what type an object is. JavaScript only has a few basic types (array, undefined, string, number, boolean and function), however, there's a hidden property that you can use to separate a RegEx or a date from an object.

```
// this function was taken from https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/08/08/fixing-the-javascript-typeof-operator/
function toType(obj) {
  return ({}).toString.call(obj).match(/\s([a-zA-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase();
}

typeof /aregex/ === "object" // true
typeof new Date() === "object" // true

toType(/aregex/) === "regexp" // true
toType(new Date()) === "date" // true
```

For some more inspiration, you can take a look at [my experimental property browser](http://codepen.io/Azeirah/pen/NPpxEr?editors=011), it supports numbers, objects, booleans and functions.

Since I couldn't answer your question precisely, I hope this general information can help you find the answer.